# Sql Query Merging column with same value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The scenario is below:

There were both product named 'A' and `B` which sold previous time.
Nowadays, this product already combined and renamed as 'C'

Let's say for example:

```
CompanyName  ProductName  PurchaseDate  ExpiredDate
CompanyA         A           2016          2017
CompanyA         B           2017          2018
CompanyA         c           2020          2021
```

A same company brought the product overtime, the year state as behind is the purchased date and expired date for the specific product

However, now product `A` and `B` is no longer be sold, which combined into product 'C'. So for report displaying, the new product will always be shown, which is `C` in this case.
I try query as below

```
SELECT * FROM Product CASE WHEN ProductName IN ('A' and 'B') THEN 'C' ELSE ProductName END ProductName
```

However, after performing the above action, the past record of `A` and `B` already change to `C` and it will appear duplicate result as follow:

```
CompanyName  ProductName  PurchaseDate  ExpiredDate
CompanyA         C           2016          2017
CompanyA         C           2017          2018
CompanyA         c           2020          2021
```

So I am thinking that, is that a way for merge those rows? and the result may look like this

`CompanyA C 2016 2021`

If I am not wrong, after performing the merging, I have to deal with `MIN` and `MAX`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use aggregation with a `case` expression:

```
select (case when productname in ('A', 'B') then 'C' else productname end) as productname,
       min(startyear), max(endyear)
from product
group by (case when productname in ('A', 'B') then 'C' else productname end)
```

Comment: hi @GordonLinoff  thanks again for your answer, always simple. short and clear :D
However, are you going to make an update according to **AziMez** suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

A few Edit on **Gordon Linoff** suggestion.

```
select CompanyName  ,(case when ProductName in ('A', 'B') then 'C' else ProductName end) as ProductName,
       min(PurchaseDate  ) as PurchaseDate   , max(ExpiredDate) as ExpiredDate
from product
group by (case when ProductName in ('A', 'B') then 'C' else ProductName end) ;
```